# Java version - compile libraries versus JRE

Tags: java

I'm trying to determine if java programs I write will run on a user's computers that may have only Java 8 or Java 11.

On my Windows 10 laptop, I have 4 Java versions installed; jdk1.8.0_281, jdk-12.0.2, jre1.8.0_311, and zulu-11.

Querying the java version in the command prompt yields

openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.52+13-CA (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.52+13-CA (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)

The Apache NetBeans IDE shows I have Java Platforms 1.8, 11, and 12.  12 is the default.

If I build a small System Info application (using System.getProperty("java.version"))  with Java 8 or 11 platforms and run it within NetBeans, it reports

This computer is running Java version 1.8.0_281
or
This computer is running Java version 11.0.13

However if I run the program from Windows (outside NetBeans) it reports

**This computer is running Java version 12.0.2**

I'm confused.

Comment: You can use `javap -v ClassName` in the command line and check the major version (table here: https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/) to see the version of Java your class was compiled with.

Comment: Windows (outside NetBeans) use the `PATH` environment variable to find executables; selecting the first listed directory containing the executable (with the name given on the command line). Try the `PATH` command (or `echo %PATH%`) to check its settings || BTW `java -version` and `javac -version` should show the versions of the virtual machine and compiler respectively

Comment: Using `where java` in the command prompt will show you which executable was picked, then you can check the PATH to see its position.